# Get value from post method to views from a for loop

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get a value from template to views.py of a django project. I am able to get the value of `name="city"` correctly but unable to get the exact value of `name="category"` in my views, instead I am getting the first element value for all the other elements in the loop. 
An idea to solve this will be very much helpful.

```
#category.html

{% for test in mytypes %}
<form id="myform" action="{% url 'my_city_category' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<a href="javascript: submitform()">
<div class="col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xl-2 hover-box mt-2 text-center"> 
    <div class="pb-1 pt-2">
            <img src="{{test.icon_image.url}}" width="100"/>
            <h6 class="mt-3 text-body text-capitalize text-decoration-none">{{ test.category_type }}</h6>
            <input type="hidden" name="category" value="{{ test.category_type }}"># unable to repeat the value while calling it in the views, stuck at the first value
            <input type="hidden" name="city" value="{{ city }}"> #rendering the exact value
            
        </div>
</div>
</a>
</form>
{% empty %}
<h6 class="mt-3 text-body text-capitalize text-decoration-none">No Categories Listed</h6>
{% endfor %}
```

```
#views.py
def City_specific_page(request):
    city = request.POST.get('city')
    category = request.POST.get('category') 
    business= Business.objects.filter(city__City=city, type__category_type=category)
    return render(request, 'community_app/type_detail_city.html',{'business':business,'category':category,'city':city})
```

```
#urls.py
path('City', views.City_specific_page, name='my_city_category'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `<form>` in your template includes the following tag:

```html
<a href="javascript: submitform()">
```

I suspect that your `submitform` function is submitting the first form on the page, rather than the one that was clicked.

You can quickly determine if this is the problem by adding a submit button inside your `<form>` tags. Make sure it's not inside the `<a>` tags, eg:

```html
<form id="myform" action="{% url 'my_city_category' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit">Test</button>
<a href="javascript: submitform()">
<!-- the rest of your form code -->
```

Click the button labelled 'Test' to see if the correct form data is submitted.

Comment: You are correct, it is a issue my java script. Thanks for your input.